# Checking validity of userid

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to display user exist when registering new user to prevent same name registered many times.this is my model code.

```
class ModelUser extends CI_Model {

public function creatAccount()
{
    $userId =   $_POST['user_id'];
    $password   =   sha1($_POST['password']);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'Userid',     

    trim|required|valid_userid|is_unique[account.user_id]|xss_clean');
    if ($this->form_valudation == false)
        return 'User already exist'
        }else
   {
     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO account(user_id,password)
    VALUES ('$userId','$password'')");
    }
```

Comment: Syntax error in $this->form_validation->set line

Comment: Please correct the quotes error in many place.

Comment: Also, in the `if` clause `form_valudation` is a typo. This is just sloppy. Clean it up.

Comment: Ok noted. Errors because it was typed using tablet. Actual codes no typing error. Only thing is that codes correct to check user validity or any other way to write

Answer (score 1):

First You have to load form validation in constructor,

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Now In creatAccount function

```
public function creatAccount()
{
    $userId =   $this->input->post('user_id');
    $password   =   sha1( $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id','Userid', 'trim|required|is_unique[tablename.coloumnname]|xss_clean');
     if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO account(user_id,password)
    VALUES ('$userId','$password')");

            }else{
         return false;
}


    }
```

Comment: This is what i have in controller, so do i have to add the first line here.                                    public function register_account()
{
    $query = $this->modeluser->creatAccount();